# Module meta-language in Racket

Tags: racket, require, metalanguage

I'm trying to write in Racket a module meta-language `mylang`, which accepts a second language to which is passes the modified body, such that:

```lisp
(module foo mylang typed/racket body)
```

is equivalent to:

```lisp
(module foo typed/racket transformed-body)
```

where the `typed/racket` part can be replaced with any other module language, of course.

I attempted a simple version which leaves the body unchanged. It works fine [on the command-line](http://pasterack.org/pastes/24047), but gives the following error when run in DrRacket:

```lisp
/usr/share/racket/pkgs/typed-racket-lib/typed-racket/typecheck/tc-toplevel.rkt:479:30: require: namespace mismatch;
 reference to a module that is not available
  reference phase: 1
  referenced module: "/usr/share/racket/pkgs/typed-racket-lib/typed-racket/env/env-req.rkt"
  referenced phase level: 0 in: add-mod!
```

Here's the whole code:

```lisp
#lang racket

(module mylang racket
  (provide (rename-out [-#%module-begin #%module-begin]))
  (require (for-syntax syntax/strip-context))
  (define-syntax (-#%module-begin stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ lng . rest)
       (let ([lng-sym (syntax-e #'lng)])
         (namespace-require `(for-meta -1 ,lng-sym))
         (with-syntax ([mb (namespace-symbol->identifier '#%module-begin)])
           #`(mb . #,(replace-context #'mb #'rest))))])))

(module foo (submod ".." mylang) typed/racket/base
  (ann (+ 1) Number))

(require 'foo)
```

---

**Requirements (i.e. solutions I'd rather avoid):**

- Adding a `(require (only-in typed/racket))` inside the `mylang` module makes this work, but I'm interested in a general solution, where `mylang` does not need to know about `typed/racket` at al (i.e. if somebody adds a new language `foo`, then `mylang` should work with it out of the box).
- Also, I'm not interested in tricks which declare a submodule and immediately `require` and re-`provide` it, [as is done here](https://github.com/AlexKnauth/dotmethod/blob/master/dotmethod/lang/reader.rkt#L29), because this changes the path to the actual module (so `main` and `test` loose their special behaviour, for example).

  It is also slower at compile-time, as submodules get [visited](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28tech._visit%29) and/or [instantiated](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28tech._instantiation%29) more times (this can be seen by writing `(begin-for-syntax (displayln 'here))`, and has a noticeable impact for large `typed/racket` programs.
- Bonus points if the arrows in DrRacket work for built-ins provided by the delegated-to language, e.g. have arrows from `ann`, `+` and `Number` to `typed/racket/base`, in the example above.

Comment: I am inclined to think this is a bug in Typed Racket -- but I don't know enough about the internals of Typed Racket to know for sure. @sam-tobin-hochstadt

Comment: Note: I am basing this on the odd error location alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do, which I don't think violates your requirements, is put it in a module, fully expand that module, and then match on the `#%plain-module-begin` to insert a require.

```
#lang racket

(module mylang racket
  (provide (rename-out [-#%module-begin #%module-begin]))
  (define-syntax (-#%module-begin stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ lng . rest)
       (with-syntax ([#%module-begin (datum->syntax #f '#%module-begin)])
         ;; put the code in a module form, and fully expand that module
         (define mod-stx
           (local-expand
            #'(module ignored lng (#%module-begin . rest))
            'top-level
            (list)))
         ;; pattern-match on the #%plain-module-begin form to insert a require
         (syntax-case mod-stx (module #%plain-module-begin)
           [(module _ lng (#%plain-module-begin . mod-body))
            #'(#%plain-module-begin
                (#%require lng)
                .
                mod-body)]))])))

;; Yay the check syntax arrows work!
(module foo (submod ".." mylang) typed/racket/base
  (ann (+ 1) Number))

(require 'foo)
```

And if you wanted to transform the body in some way, you could do that either before or after expansion.

The pattern-matching to insert the extra `(#%require lng)` is necessary because expanding the module body in a context where `lng` is available isn't enough. Taking the `mod-body` code back out of the `module` form means that the bindings will refer to `lng`, but `lng` won't be available at run-time. That's why I get the `require: namespace mismatch; reference to a module that is not available` error without it, and that's why it needs to be added after expansion.

#### Update from comments

However, as @GeorgesDupéron pointed out in a comment, this introduces another problem. If `lng` provides an identifier `x` and the module where it is used imports a different `x`, there will be an import conflict where there shouldn't be. Require lines should be in a "nested scope" with respect to the module language so that they can shadow identifiers like `x` here.

@GeorgesDupéron found a solution to this problem in this [email on the racket users list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/sS-pUUGp9o4/hHTR56diDQAJ), using `(make-syntax-introducer)` on the `mod-body` to produce the nested scope.

```
(module mylang racket
  (provide (rename-out [-#%module-begin #%module-begin]))
  (define-syntax (-#%module-begin stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ lng . rest)
       (with-syntax ([#%module-begin (datum->syntax #f '#%module-begin)])
         ;; put the code in a module form, and fully expand that module
         (define mod-stx
           (local-expand
            #'(module ignored lng (#%module-begin . rest))
            'top-level
            (list)))
         ;; pattern-match on the #%plain-module-begin form to insert a require
         (syntax-case mod-stx (module #%plain-module-begin)
           [(module _ lng (#%plain-module-begin . mod-body))
            #`(#%plain-module-begin
                (#%require lng)
                .
                #,((make-syntax-introducer) #'mod-body))]))])))
```

Comment: That's a nice solution!

Comment: Thanks again! A subtle corner case I encountered: if `foo` requires a module (e.g. `type-expander`) which shadows some of the bindings exported by `typed/racket/base`, it will conflict with the inserted `(#%require lng)` (because module-language bindings can be shadowed by the `(require type-expander)`, but `require`d bindings cannot be shadowed by another `require`). Changing the inserted `(#%require lng)` to `(#%require (only lng))` seems to be enough to have the module available, without actually importing any bindings which might clash with other `require`d modules.

Comment: And I've changed it again based on your email on the list